# Seg fault with default allocation std::set<void*>

Tags: c++, stl, stdset

I am trying to learn STL allocators for void*. Here is my code

```
#include <set>
#include <memory>

class Test {
 public:
    std::set<void*> GetAllInformation() { return info_set_; }

 private:
    std::set<void*> info_set_;
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test> test_obj_;

    const auto info = test_obj_->GetAllInformation();
    if (info.empty())
        std::cout << "info empty";

    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting Segmentation fault at

Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

0x00402a18 in std::_Rb_tree<void*, void*, std::_Identity<void*>, std::less<void*>, std::allocator<void*> >::_M_root (this=0x0) at C:/Program Files (x86)/mingw-w64/i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:733

The stl_tree.h

```
      _Const_Base_ptr
      _M_root() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return this->_M_impl._M_header._M_parent; }
```

could anyone help to explain?
Thanks

Comment: Seg fault is because of `test_obj_->GetAllInformation()` since `test_obj_` doesn't point to any `Test` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **problem** is that currently `test_obj_` is not pointing to any `Test` object. Thus the expression `test_obj_->GetAllInformation()` leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just **crash**(which is what happens in your case).

For example, [here](https://onlinegdb.com/qy0bNunmpx) the program doesn't crash but [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nCLECeGv1TRLkR7T) it crashes.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>